# SOAP End Point Id Clarification

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex, enterprise-wsdl

I want to know whats the significance of the ID "0DFm00000007Om6" in the following SOAP WS Stub, I see this is only added for enterprise WSDL Stub endpoints not for partner WSDL Stub endpoints, is it something to differentiate this two?

```
public class Soap { 
                public String endpoint_x = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFm00000007Om6'; 
                public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x; 
                public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x; 
                public String clientCertName_x; 
                public String clientCert_x; 
                public String clientCertPasswd_x; 
                public Integer timeout_x; 
                ..............

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0DF` is the key (Object ID) prefix for VersionSet - 0DFm00000007Om6 is not universal; this ID is for the object that represents your encoded package version selections when your enterprise WSDL was generated.

Comment: is it same between production and sandboxes or it varies?